# Can we use multiple GTM container in android application, when we are creating GTM container using Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

Can we use multiple GTM containers in android application, when we are creating GTM container using Firebase?

I found example [here](https://www.tatvic.com/blog/quick-guide-adding-multiple-google-tag-manager-containers-single-android-app/), but in the example, `data-layer` are using for sending event and I want it using through Firebase GTM container.

For this I created two GTM container, download both JSON file of containers and paste it in `assets > containers` folder. I have configured different GA tracking Id with each GTM container, but when I run application only one GA tracking ID is showing event and data.

Now I want to know that :

- Can we use more than one GTM container ID using Firebase in android application?
- If yes then how can we check that both GTM container is working?

Comment: Hi, do you have maybe any updates on this topic? I'm also interested in running multiple containers/switch between them based on the remote config flag.